# eCryptfs on ubuntu server : How to keep the home mounted without being over ssh?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, home-directory, ecryptfs

I have a daemon program who need to read in a file who is saved somewhere in my home folder.

But every time I close my ssh connection, this daemon can't read the file because it appear that eCryptfs unmount the home.

Maybe there is an option to force eCryptfs to not only mount with an ssh connection ? I didn't found it.

Thanks.

PS : I know this thread, https://askubuntu.com/questions/165608/why-is-ecryptfs-only-mounting-private-home-directory-over-ssh, but this is not the proper/good way to deal with the request.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove auto-umount file from ~/.ecryptfs/ - each time you will need to umount your private directory manually. The other option is to keep your ssh session running using screen or tmux.

[More info on ecryptfs Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedPrivateDirectory)

Comment: You mean :
- keeping an ssh session on localhost inside screen ? Yes that should work.
- removing auto-unmount still keep the system secure ?

Comment: Well, that depends on what kind of security you need. Generally it's always better to umount the directory when you're not using it.

Comment: Ok and if I want the feature back, I just to re create a simple file "auto-umount" ?

Comment: Yes, just create an empty file: touch ~/.ecryptfs/auto-umount

Comment: or in ubuntu /home/.ecryptfs/{USER}/.ecryptfs/ . Same for auto-mount